# array that is being logged is showing up as blank when returned

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm dealing with a very frustrating issue where I can console.log an array, but when I try to return it, it returns as a blank array with no length.

Below is the code, the input it is getting is like [0.1234]. Optionally there are other parameters, but those are not needed for now. Without them, it is just returns an array. Actually just the input. Well that's what I want it to do.

In the else suite, I console.log(oArr) and it logs fine, but when I return it, it returns a blank array. There you will also see I had to transfer i, the input parameter, to an input var because when I tried checking the length of it inside the setTimeout, it was giving a length of zero even though when I was logging it, what was being logged did not have a length of zero. But when I assigned it to a new var, it worked fine. The reason the setTimeout exists is because the for-loop doesn't run unless I use the setTimeout to put it next in the queue.

```
function runV(i, l, y){
    var a=[],o=[],x={};
    if(i[1]!==undefined){
        a=i[0];
        if(i.length>1) i=i[1];
        else i=undefined;
        setTimeout(function(){
            for(var j=0; j<a.length; j++){
                var oArr=[];
                oArr.push(a[j]);
                if(i===undefined){
                    if(y!==undefined) o=y.activate(oArr);
                    else return oArr;
                }
                else{
                    if(y!==undefined) x['adverbs']=y.activate(oArr);
                    else return oArr;
                }
            }
        }, 0);
        if(i!==undefined){
            for(var j=0; j<i.length; j++){
                var oArr=[];
                oArr.push(i[j]);
                if(l!==undefined) x['emotions']=l.activate(oArr);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        var input;
        setTimeout(function(){
            input=i;
            for(var j=0; j<input.length; j++){
                var oArr=[];
                oArr.push(i[j]);
                console.log(oArr);
                if(l!==undefined) o=l.activate(oArr);
                return oArr;
            }
        }, 0);
    }
    if(x.adverbs!==undefined) return x;
    return o;
}
```

Comment: You're returning it from an anonymous function

Comment: The function in `setTimeout` runs asynchronously. You can't return something from that. `runV` returns when it starts the timer, it doesn't wait for it to finish.

Comment: @iccthedral There's nothing wrong with returning from an anonymous function, the problem is returning from an asynchronous function.

Comment: @Barmar that's right. Then how do I return oArr? the for-loop was not running unless it was in the setTimeout

Comment: I can't think of any reason why the for-loop wouldn't run normally.

Comment: @Barmar could it be due to memory? I was using a lot of memory in this project.

Comment: It uses the same amount of memory either way.

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing? Your cryptic 1-letter variables don't make it obvious.

Comment: Can you post the version that didn't use `setTimeout`?

Comment: I don't understand the need of `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Barmar There is something wrong, in this context; as he obviously needs to return from the outer function. But of course, I get what you mean.

Comment: `vectorise('hello')` returns an empty array, because it also uses `setTimeout`.

Comment: `runV(vectorise('hello'))` is equivalent to `runV([])` because `vectorise` returns an empty array.

Comment: @Barmar okay, I don't think the overwrite happened. It now does not have the setTimeout

Comment: You need to remove `setTimeout` from all the functions. When you call `setTimeout`, the function you give it will not run until after the caller returns, so there's no way that the timeout function can alter any of its variables.

Comment: @Barmar copy and paste the vectorise function in the console and then run it. See it works fine then

Comment: @Barmar There are no returns in the setTImeouts of vectorise. So there should be no problem there, right?

Comment: It still has the `setTimeout`. I pasted it into the console, it didn't work, it returned `[]`

Comment: @Barmar removing all of them worked. Can you please put that as an answer. To remove the setTimeout from runV and vectorise functions because setTimeout runs asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a result from a function run via `setTimeout`. You need to remove this from all your functions, and run that code directly in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning your result from anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   ...
   else return oArr; 
   ...
}, 0);
```

if you want to use this construction you should use callback function as an argument to "runV" function.

Comment: Then how do I return oArr? the for-loop was not running unless it was in the setTimeout

Comment: It is still going on, take a look here: http://the-irf.com/deep/lstm.html. In the console, run runV(vectorise('hello')); and you get a blank array. When I paste and enter those functions' definitions into the console then run them, then it works. But how does that help my implementation.

Comment: vectorise('hello') returning empty array did you try to use debugger from browser?